# Continuity of a function on a square

Tags: integration, continuity

Fix some $\ell\in\mathbb{R}^+$, and say I have a function $f:[0,\ell]\times[0,\ell]\to\mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

1. $f(s,t)$ is continuous everywhere except when $s=t$, where it is undefined.
2. For fixed $t$, $\lim_{s\to t}f(s,t)=0$.

We then also define $F(t)=\int_0^\ell f(s,t)\,ds$, which we know exists for all $t$ because of the properties above.  I'm attempting to answer the following:

- Can we conclude that $F(t)$ is continuous?
- Is $f(s,t)$ continuous if we define $f(s,t)=0$ when $s=t$?
- How should I be trying to approach this problem?

Comment: I can't say I agree entirely, however I did find this essentially similar question affirming that $F$ is continuous, my apologies. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575253/continuity-of-a-function-defined-by-an-integral

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Consider $$f(s,t)=((s-t)^2)^{-t}$$

If this function fits the criteria you stated however $$F(t)=\int^{\ell}_{0}((s-t)^2)^{-t}ds=[\frac{((s-t)^2)^{-t}(s-t)}{2t-1}]^{\ell}_{0}=\frac{((\ell-t)^2)^{-t}(\ell-t)}{2t-1}-\frac{((-t)^2)^{-t}(-t)}{2t-1}$$

$$F(t)=\frac{((\ell -t)^2)^{-t}(\ell-t)-((-t)^2)^{-t}(-t)}{2t-1}$$

clearly $F(t)$ is not defined at point $t=\frac{1}{2}$, let alone continuous at this point.

I came to the decision to look for a contradicting function which fits your criteria after considering that your criteria does imply continuity implications on the implicit integral $\int f(s,t)ds$, that is only for fixed $t$ and I could see no relation to the continuity with $s$ fixed and $t$ varied. I would love to know what you think?

Comment: It seems that your suggested function does not satisfy property 2?  Observe that $\lim_{s\to t}((s-t)^2)^{-t}=\lim_{s\to t}\frac{1}{(s-t)^{2t}}=\infty$.  Is there an error in your definition of $f$?

Comment: That is true perhaps, though what about a constant function (where it is defined) $f_2(s,t)=f(s,t)-f(s,t)$. Maybe others less trivial can be come up with. Put the function in the denominator of another function. Maybe I'm wrong but this is the building blocks of $f(s,t)$'s such that $F(t)$'s aren't continuous as hypothesized in your question?

Comment: The constant function $f_2$ is indeed continuous if we define $f(s,t)=0$ when $s=t$, since it is already $0$ for every other $s,t$.  And hence $F(t)$ will also be continuous.

I'm not sure what you're saying in your last sentence--would you mind clarifying?

Comment: To clarify the last statement I am saying your question is a statement about the continuity of $F(t)$ given the prior statements. It only requires one counter example to answer your first question with an affirmative No. The $f(s,t)$ I provided does not satisfy your 2nd statement, however it is possible to construct such a statement which does, from it. Does that clarify it? Is there any inconsistency?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to construct a function $f(s,t)$ that satisfies both properties 1 and 2, but results in a discontinuous $F(t)$.  Of course, I'll immediately change my mind if I see a proof that such a counterexample exists.

Comment: Here is another hint. If all partial derivatives of a function $J$ exist and are continuous at a point, then $J$ is differentiable at that point. If $J$ is differentiable at that point then it is continuous at that point. By the fundamental theorem of calculus $\int^{a}_{b}j(x_1,x_2)dx_1=J(a)-J(b)$ where $j=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}J$. We know $j$ is continuous almost everywhere (for sake lets say everywhere) but that is just one partial derivative of $J$, we require all of them to conclude the continuity of $J(a)-J(b)$.

Comment: If you assume that $j$ is continuous everywhere on a compact set, you immediately have that $J(x_2)=\int_a^b j(x_1,x_2)\,dx_1$ will be continuous.  Just because you can't prove continuity by looking at the derivatives of $J$ doesn't mean it's not continuous.  There are many continuous functions with nonexistent derivatives; for example, consider $f(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42822/discussion-between-marshal-craft-and-aegiscruiser).